# Wrong close reason bug, everything must be about video games?

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

It seems that every close panel on stackoverflow.com is showing the wrong off-topic message for me.

"[image: All video games, all the time.]

> This question does not appear to be about videogames or videogame
>   consoles within the scope defined in the help center."

**Edit**

Doing a full browser close and cache clear made the problem 'go away', as a naively optimistic programmer would say.

Comment: No repro here... :(

Comment: We got bored with all that programming stuff, now it's time for games!

Comment: **Reproduced**, all though for me it was "This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center."

Comment: For me it's just about plain old programming. No fair :( I demand that this bug be rolled out to all users to guarantee equal treatment.

Comment: Bug?? You mean I wasn't supposed to close all of those programming questions?

Comment: [Information security for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jihfi.png)!

Comment: Interestingly it seems stable on a per user basis. Mine has been consistently English language even while other people are reporting other off topic sites

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Off topic because "this question does not appear to be about Information security in English language video games". This could get _really_ specific.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

My fault, caching close reasons is... probably not something I should have attempted coming off of NyQuil.

Comment: One day, there needs to be a book about SE's best commit messages. It would make a great seasonal gift for committed users

Answer (score 6):

What? Video games? No, everything has to be about English language and usage. Where'd you get video games from?

[image: A Stack Overflow off topic reason which reads: "This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center."]

(repro'd in Firefox Aurora 27.02a. What's going on here?)

Comment: looooool ------

Comment: We don't need the [wheel of blame](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/) on this one, we need the "wheel of what stack overflow is about this second"