# Why is the close reason for this question from another stack?

Tags: bug, closed-questions, close-reasons

This question was recently closed on Arts&Crafts.SE

https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/2066/freelance-artist-needs-to-earn-extra-cash

In case something changes this is the close text:

[image: Close reason text]

> "This question does not appear to be about programação, within the scope defined in the [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)."

It looks like something from the Portuguese Stack Overflow. What is going on here?

I have not seen a recent question about this but I have a tendency to asks dupes here.

Comment: As a note, this close message read correctly when it was initially closed.

Comment: Half-reproduced on Worldbuilding (only "help center" is translated, not "programming").

Comment: [status-norepro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/govIC.png). Must be [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207281/wrong-close-reason-bug-everything-must-be-about-video-games for an earlier occurrence of a similar problem.

Comment: @Gilles It's always caching. Except when its not.

Comment: Seen now on [Aviation](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30606/3427). Notably, the help center link goes to http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help